# Python unzip recursively from source to another destination

Tags: python, unzip, os.walk

i don't know how to solve this simple task, i want recursively exctract all zip/rar files from a source folder to another destination folder re-creating the same tree. At the moment i already create the source and destination folder trees but i don't know how to extract iside the destination.

Thanks...
Scacchi

```
# Required patool and pyunpack
import errno
import os, zipfile, pyunpack
from tkinter import Tk, filedialog, PhotoImage

root = Tk() # pointing root to Tk() to use it as Tk() in program.
root.withdraw() # Hides small tkinter window.
root.attributes('-topmost', True)
basis_folder = filedialog.askdirectory(title='Select source folder Compressed files')
extrac_folder = filedialog.askdirectory(title='Select destination folder for Un-Compressed') 

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(basis_folder):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(".rar") :
            print('RAR:'+os.path.join(root,filename))
        elif filename.endswith(".zip"):
            print('ZIP:'+os.path.join(root,filename))
        name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0]
        print (name)
        if filename.endswith(".rar") or filename.endswith(".zip"):
            try:
                arch = pyunpack.Archive(os.path.join(root,filename))
                # os.mkdir(name)
                arch.extractall(directory=root)
                # os.remove(os.path.join(root,filename))
            except Exception as e:
                print("ERROR: BAD ARCHIVE "+os.path.join(root,filename))
                print(e)
                try:
                    # os.path.join(root,filename)os.remove(filename)
                    pass
                except OSError as e: # this would be "except OSError, e:" before Python 2.6
                    if e.errno != errno.ENOENT: # errno.ENOENT = no such file or directory
                        raise # re-raise exception if a different error occured
```

Comment: You can either build the path depth-first and store the path as a stack in a string, or just use `os.chdir` for changing the path manually.

Comment: Thank you, but i'm trying to figure out how to remoe first folder in path.
For instance: 
d:\folder_base\folder1\folder2\folder3\xxx.zip   source folder
d:\folder_exctact\folder1\folder2\folder3\xxx       destination folder

i don't know how to extract the file xxx.zip to another base folder (folder_extract) in same subfolder structure